# Is the global minimum of a nonconvex function over a constrained set the maxmin of the corresponding Lagrangian?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, non-convex-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Let a nonconvex differentiable function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and differentiable constraint $g(x)\leq 0$, with $X$ convex.

Does the **global minimum** of $f$, $f(x^\star)$, with $g(x^\star)\leq 0$ coincide with the maxmin value of the corresponding Lagrangian function?

I.e., does the following hold true:
\begin{equation}
    f(x^\star) \stackrel{?}{=} \max_{\lambda\geq 0} \min_{x\in X} \{ f(x)+ \lambda g(x) \}.
\end{equation}

Comment: I believe so, if $x$ isn't in the constaint set $g(x)\leq 0$ then $\max_{\lambda\geq 0} \{ f(x)+ \lambda g(x) \}$ would be infinity. Therefore, the rhs must satisfy the constraints (if the problem is feasible). If the constraints are satisfied ($g(x)\leq 0$) then $\lambda = 0$ maximizes the expression. Therefore, the rhs is the min of $f$ that satisfies the constraints, i.e., $f(x^*)$.

Comment: Just as an additional remark, if $x^*$ is optimal then it will satisfy the KKT conditions. If a point satisfies the KKT conditions it might not necessarily be optimal (it is optimal if it satisfies regularity conditions / constraint qualifications).

Comment: The lagrangian solution gives us stationary points.

Comment: As far as I know, a (local) optimum satisfies the KKT conditions only if some constraint qualification holds. A KKT point need not always be a (local) optimum even if a constraint qualification holds. In my question I assume that the global optimum satisfies a constraint qualification/ is a KKT point.

Answer (score 0):

This is sometimes true, but not true in general. The difference
$$f(x^*) - \max_{\lambda \ge 0} \min_{x \in X} L(x, \lambda)$$
is called the [Duality Gap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_gap). If $f$ and $g$ are convex, and $g$ satisfies some mild conditions, such as [Slater's Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_condition), then you can be sure that the duality gap is $0$.

Comment: In general due to weak duality, we know that for the lagrangian function:
$$ \min_x \max_\lambda \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) \geq \max_\lambda \min_x \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda).$$

The duality gap ($\min \max \mathcal{L} - \max\min \mathcal{L}$) is in general non-negative. But, what I am asking is not related to strong duality. I want to know whether the global minimum $x^*$ of the problem corresponds (under some constraint qualification) to the point $(x^*, \lambda^*)$ such that:
$$\mathcal{L}(x^*, \lambda^*) = \max_\lambda \min_x \mathcal{L}(x,\lambda)$$.